# Two entity manager instances when making update in the first one the second one selects the old value

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I'm using hibernate entity manager 3.4.0.GA and i have the flowing problem:
I have two entity manager instances **em1** and **em2** and i have one entity. I update the the entity in **em1** and then select it in **em2**, but **em2** makes select against database but in the entity there is the old value (before the update). What i'm doing wrong :(

the exact steps are in **em1** (T1) i fetch the entity and update it then commit T1 and the changes are in the database, then in **em2** (T2) i make jpa query that fetch all entities, but the entity (that i updated successfuly in T1) holds the old value because its readed from 1st level cache :(.

Comment: Are you doing that in the same transaction? Did you check that `em2` actually issues a SQL query and does not just try and read the entity from its first level cache?

Answer (score 3):

**Level - 1 :** The scope of this cache is `EntityManager` or the `PersistenceContext` (not used to Hibernate, but it will be session probably).

**Level - 2 :** Its scope is `EntityManagerFactory` & the cached objects can be retrieved by any entitymanager in the application.

As you are using two different entitymanager, the object isn't loaded from 1st level cache, but from 2nd level cache. Therefore retrieving stale objects from it.

- You can try `session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH)`.

  Else, you can set hint in the query itself.

  `@NamedQuery(name="queryWithNoCache",
              query="SELECT e FROM Entity e",
              hints={@QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheMode", value="REFRESH")})`

  You can try other modes also, accordingly.
- Ehcache Documentation :

  > Session.find does not use the cache for the primary object. Hibernate
  >   will try to use the cache for any associated objects. Session.find
  >   does however cause the cache to be populated. Query.find works in
  >   exactly the same way. Use these where the chance of getting a cache
  >   hit is low.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use em1.flush() after the update :)

Comment: it will flush the **em1** but update in em1 is fine. my problem is that this entity is loaded from 1st lv cache in **em2**

Comment: yes it will update the state in **em1** but the state is fine in **em1** i want to refresh it in **em2** but i'm using jpql query there :(

Comment: i dont't know ..if you use a namedQuery add an "Hint"  ..for example:                 @NamedQuery(name = "findEmployeesByDepartmentId", 
            query = "select o from Employee o where o.department.id = :departmentId"), 
            hints = {@QueryHint(name=QueryHints.REFRESH, value=HintValues.TRUE)}   look here http://soadev.blogspot.it/2010/02/ejb-with-eclipselink-how-to-ensure-that.html